# Java/JSTL: is it a good idea to put all URLs in an enum?

Tags: java, jsp, enums, jstl

I'm working on a web app with Java servlets and JSP pages with JSTL.

I'd like to find a way to:

1) Easily refactor URLs

2) For any url, easily discover exactly what pages/servlets reference it. This way when making changes it should be easier to know the potential impact elsewhere.

I'm considering using an enum to store URLs.

Is this a good idea? If so, what's the best way to reference it via JSTL? Is there an alternative way to achieve the same goal?

```
//example code
public enum SiteUrl {
    HOME("/"),CART("/cart"),PROFILE("/my-profile");

    private final String url;

    private SiteUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You can define all this navigation-related stuff in the deployment descriptor file(s). Putting it into code is a retrograde step.

Comment: Hello, could you explain more on why it's a retrograde step? I'd like to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer DB rather then enum. Reasons as below:

- Not easy to maintain the enum class because other people need to
  update it too.
- If your application is not support hot-deploy, u need to restart app
  when add a new url.
- Normally, u need to handle request at first, like clean parameters
  part, before direct.A DB interface can do this.

Comment: For the class that retrieves URLs from the DB, will it have 1 method for each url, or a general purpose method that takes a param?

Comment: both DB structure and interface is base on your real requirement and design. I assume one URL with different parameters direct to one JSP. But it takes more time on DB interaction, yours' is faster. So you need to consider your application's real environment.